# Save files based upon cell in Excel file

Tags: matlab

I have an excel file that is 20 rows and 81 columns. The first column in each row contains a code and the rest of the columns contain values.

I want to create a *.mat file for each row and save it using the name of the code located in the first column.

For example, if I have a row that looks like the following:

```
202   100   200   300  400
```

Then the resulting data should be saved to "202.mat"

```
100   200   300  400
```

I have this code so far:

```
allData = xlsread('matlab2.xlsx');
names = allData(1,1:1); 
values = allData(1,2:81);
```

Comment: Do you have a *.mat file containing the 20x81 data or is that an excel file? Based on  your example it's an excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have `allData` as you have stated in your problem, you can simply do the following.

```
names = allData(:,1);
values = allData(:,2:end);

for k = 1:numel(names)
    matfilename = sprintf('%s.mat', names{k});
    data = [values{k,:}];
    save(matfilename, 'data');
end
```

This will create a .mat file with the variable `data` saved it in containing the data you have.

Comment: Thank you sever, 
I've tried your code but I only obtain different files  such as ұ.mat ԕ.mat...
no one called as the code and containing values

Comment: @HamgevaVage is the code always a number? If so, try my edit where I use '%d' rather than '%s' in the `sprintf` call.